# How did the dunces figure out who won?

Tags: lateral-thinking

Three dunces named Dial, Moon and Sun are having a race. The race starts at sunrise and ends at mid day. They don't know how to count, they can't mark the track in any way, and no outside help is allowed. The track is perfectly circular. But by the end of the day they figured out that Dial had passed the "finish line". What process did the dunces use to figure this out? How did they know where the finish line was?
Feedback appreciated. Hope you enjoy.

**Hint**:

> their names.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This does not appear to be logical deduction - please check tags before using them.

Comment: (Also, I suggest adding more details to narrow it down. Right now, it seems likely that this will be closed as too broad.)

Comment: (Oof. You just changed the puzzle...)

Comment: I'm sorry excuse my horrible english.Im still learning it.Didnt know the difference until I read it again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Notice**: When this answer was posted the puzzle was asking how they would know *who went around the most times*,  not *how they knew where the finish line was*.

**New answer**:

> they used a sundial to create the line. This also acts as a timer. They can use any shadow, even their *own shadows*.

**Old answers**:

> they can't mark **the track** in any way,

However,

> They can mark *off* of the track.

Alternatively,

> they use the letters of their names instead of numbers.

For instance,

> when Dial goes around once, that's *D*. Another time, that's *I*. However, this only works if they go around not more than 4 times, which is a bit hard to believe seeing how long the race lasts.

Comment: I dont think the letters one would work since dial and moon only have 4 letters so they'd end in a tie

Comment: @VictorGonzalez It's a sundial.

Comment: I think you're unto something

Comment: Well in that you're right! I was thinking about them literally looking at the sun and as soon as they could no longer see it that meant the race was over.But your solution is much more elegant and well is basically the same as mine.

Comment: If they cannot get outside help, this answer must be disqualified, since there's no mention in the question of any unusual (not in your pocket or part of your clothing) tools or devices, and this answer relies on one.

Comment: @jaxter see the comment above. They can even use their own shadows.

Comment: @Mithrandir So, the premise of the solution is that, in order to find the finish line, they must determine midday. Midday occurs when shadows are shortest (_not_ absent). This involves stopping to mark the line of your shadow at various points along the track to find the shortest one, and measuring them.  Since the point in a _race_ is to go the fastest, each competitor has a disincentive to carry out this time-consuming operation; whoever does it will almost certainly lose. So, it never takes place. Ergo, shadows are not a workable solution.

Comment: @Mithrandir In any case, for this method to work at all, the course must be so long that they cannot complete a lap before time has expired.  Otherwise, competitors who lap each other (and cannot count the events) will confuse the issue of who crossed the finish line first.  But once the finish line is found and marked, the one who does so will be the winner, unless he makes a mistake and is short of the actual line. If that happens, another competitor can pass him, and win. This happens unless _all of the dunces do not realize this_, and stop frequently to measure shadows. Not quite workable.